# Use of Perfect Tenses, depending on the position of the phrase 'the first time'?

Tags: present-perfect, simple-past-vs-past-perfect, future-perfect

> Today, I AM WEARING ice skates for the first time (ever).
>
> Yesterday, I WORE ice skates for the first time (ever).
>
> Tomorrow, I WILL WEAR ice skates for the first time (ever).

with the phrase 'for the first time', versus

> Today IS the first time I HAVE (ever) WORN ice skates.
>
> Yesterday WAS the first time I HAD (ever) WORN ice skates.
>
> Tomorrow WILL BE the first time I WILL HAVE (ever) WORN ice skates.

with the phrase 'it is/was/will be the first time'.

Are these tense changes correct? If they are, how come they occur, since the situations described remain the same exactly, irrespective of whether you use 'for the first time' or 'it is/was/will be the first time'?

Comment: *Ever* is implied by using *first time*, not by the perfect construction.

Comment: @Robusto: Never mind 'ever', that's not what the question is about, that's why it's in brackets!

Comment: It's not the position of *the first time* that requires the changes. You've also changed *today* to *today is*.

Comment: I don't think I understand what the question is.  _I am wearing_ isn't describing the same situation as _I have worn_, and I don't see why "the first time" matters.  Couldn't you just take that out to simplify the question?  I am wearing; I wore; I will wear; I have worn; I had worn; I will have worn (the parts you capitalized) - these are correct conjugations.

Comment: @pabrams: If you are doing something for the first time, then it is the first time you have done it! Why the change of tense, since the situation is the same exactly?! That is what the question is about.

Comment: *"I am wearing"* is not the same as *"I have worn"*; it doesn't matter if it's the first time or the millionth time.  I'll answer using an Answer.

Answer (score 1):

One of your premises, *"the situations described remain the same exactly"*, is incorrect.

The situations described by your first set of sentences are not quite the same as those described by your second set of sentences.  For example, *"I am wearing"* is not the same as *"I have worn"*; the first says that you're currently wearing something, and the latter implies that you are no longer wearing it.

If you want to change the position of that phrase without altering the meaning, there are other ways, like, for example, instead of:

> Today, I AM WEARING ice skates for the first time ever.

you could say

> Today, for the first time ever, I am wearing ice skates

or, somewhat awkwardly, in my opinion:

> I am wearing ice skates, today, for the first time ever.

I think it would help you to get rid of the extra words, when thinking about this.

> I am wearing
>
> I wore
>
> I will wear

> I have worn
>
> I had worn
>
> I will have worn

This way you don't confuse yourself as to whether the subject of the verb is "Today" or "I".
For example, in the sentence "Today is the first time I have  ever worn ice skates.", the subject of the "is" is "today" (hence the present tense), whereas the subject of the verb "wear" in the second sentence is "I", and you are already wearing the skates, so you "have worn" them (even if they are still on; the act of wearing occurs when you put the skates on your feet).